# manually getting class info (such as Fields or return type)

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete

This may be a very simple question but I honestly couldn't find an answer anywhere around.

I program with Netbeans where, when you type in the dot (.) after a known class or object, the autocomplete mode shows you Methods and Fields and these things..

I just want to know, if there's a way to get exactly this information pop-up thing manually.

Because, when there's an Object I wanna use, which has let's say 8 different inputs for its constructor and mid-way I don't remember which one I still need or in which order I'd like to just quickly mark the object and check, what it needs.

this is what I'm talking about:
[picture of autocompletion example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIBU1.png)

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: You can type Control-Space to bring up that pop up.

Comment: More important and often used commands on the cheat sheet: https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-80.pdf

Comment: thanks guys :D
how do I mark this question as solved now?   ':P

Comment: I wouldn't bother to mark it solved.  It's too simple really to make a good question.  Probably there a duplicate somewhere that we should link it too.